# Generate JS source code from a C++ AST

Tags: javascript, c++

Is there a library allowing to generate a js AST from a C++ API, then craft a source code from this AST ?

Something kinda like this :

```
Expression * expression1 = new Number(42);
Expression * expression2 = new Number(69);
Expression * result = new Addition(expression1, expression2);
Statement * stmt = new Return(result);
string code = Codegen().build(stmt); // "return ((42)+(69));"
```

Comment: Wow, I had no idea this existed: https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki

Comment: @JasonSperske yeah, it's a very nice utility ! However it does not have the AST-crafting ability (and it is not a library neither), so I can't use it in my use case.